# Facebook Request over PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-requests

I'm trying to generate a User to User Request out of my App in Facebook.

The thing is, that I only find tutorials which use JavaScript. But I want to send a Request to a Friend out of my PHP environment.

Do I have to use te Api Call somehow?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a PHP Call available to send requests to a user, you can only use the Requests JavaScript API call for this. This is there to prevent abuse of requests - by preventing automatic sending of requests in the background without the user's consent.

Comment: i found this on the facebook developers page: Direct URL Example

This example uses the the raw URL to render a Request Dialog for your app. One key difference from using this method over the JavaScript SDK is the requirement of the redirect_uri parameter.

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?
  app_id=APP_ID&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
I think this is the way to go...

Comment: this is where i found it
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/